# Dataframe to RDD[Row] replacing space with nulls

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am converting a Spark dataframe to RDD[Row] so I can map it to final schema to write into Hive Orc table. I want to convert any space in the input to actual `null` so the hive table can store actual `null` instead of a empty string.

Input DataFrame (a single column with pipe delimited values):

```
col1
1|2|3||5|6|7|||...|
```

My code:

```
inputDF.rdd.
  map { x: Row => x.get(0).asInstanceOf[String].split("\\|", -1)}.
  map { x => Row (nullConverter(x(0)),nullConverter(x(1)),nullConverter(x(2)).... nullConverter(x(200)))}


def nullConverter(input: String): String = {
  if (input.trim.length > 0) input.trim
  else null
}
```

Is there any clean way of doing it rather than calling the `nullConverter` function 200 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update based on single column:

Going with your approach, I will do something like:

```
inputDf.rdd.map((row: Row) => {
    val values = row.get(0).asInstanceOf[String].split("\\|").map(nullConverter)
    Row(values)
})
```

---

Make your nullConverter or any other logic a udf:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val nullConverter = udf((input: String) => {
  if (input.trim.length > 0) input.trim
  else null
})
```

Now, use the udf on your df and apply to all columns:

```
val convertedDf = inputDf.select(inputDf.columns.map(c => nullConverter(col(c)).alias(c)):_*)
```

Now, you can do your RDD logic.

Comment: I have only one column and it has values in pipe delimited format. I want to convert the spaces to NULLS as part of the values.

Answer (score 1):

This would be easier to do using the DataFrame API before converting to an RDD. First, split the data:

```
val df = Seq(("1|2|3||5|6|7|8||")).toDF("col0")        // Example dataframe
val df2 = df.withColumn("col0", split($"col0", "\\|")) // Split on "|"
```

Then find out the length of the array:

```
val numCols = df2.first.getAs[Seq[String]](0).length
```

Now, for each element in the array, use the nullConverter `UDF` and then assign it to it's own column.

```
val nullConverter = udf((input: String) => {
  if (input.trim.length > 0) input.trim
  else null
})

val df3 = df2.select((0 until numCols).map(i => nullConverter($"col0".getItem(i)).as("col" + i)): _*)
```

The result using the example dataframe:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|col0|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|null|   5|   6|   7|   8|null|null|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Now convert it to an RDD or continue using the data as a DataFrame depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in converting dataframe to rdd

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df = sc.parallelize([
    (1, "foo bar"), (2, "foobar "), (3, "   ")
]).toDF(["k", "v"])

df.select(regexp_replace(col("*"), " ", "NULL"))
```